# Lining two elements responsively

Tags: css, alignment, responsiveness

I'm working with a website and I want to get a h1 header on top of the page to line exactly with a specific text in a navbar below it. I don't know how to accomplish this and would appreciate some help.

The website is at [rakentajapalvelu](http://www.rakentajapalvelut.fi) and the header is at the top "Rakentajapalvelu Kivimäki Oy" and I'm trying to line it perfectly and also responsively to the word "etusivu", which is the firs word in the navbar below.

Any insight is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your h1 header may get hidden in back of nav bar...u may use index value for that..
set the index value of h1 higher than nav bar index and also set h1 as

```
float:top;
```

you may also provide its pixel distance according to requirement as:

position:absolute;

```
top:blah px;
left:blah px;
bottom: blah px;
right:blah px;
```

Comment: Thanks, I applied float:top; to the H1.  Changed the HTML slightly also. But if I apply position:absolute; to H1, it dissapears altogether. I tried also with applying position:absolute; to the header-logo rule, but it just put the header tightly to the left and top, left, bottom and right rules had no effect.

Comment: ok..try with position:relative; or may be its disappeared because you have not used index value for them...it may have hidden on backside of nav bar..In the header attributes...write z-index: blah;...the element (h1 or nav bar) which you want to come to front should have higher z-index

Comment: Thanks again, I added these rules to style.css header-logo rule: z-index: 10;
 position:relative; top:0px; left:-165px; bottom:10px; right:0px; this made the position of the header to stay inline with the navbar until the screen is under iPad size. But in mobile view the H1 disappears to the left and is unreadable.